Are GOAP & GBAB (Goal based agent behavior) the same thing?
I am reading Programming Game AI by Example. It shows a technique called Goal Based Agent Behavior, which seems very similar to GOAP.
Are these the same, or there are key differences of which I should be aware?

It might help to include a relevant excerpt of the book you're reading, showing how it defines GBAB. Not all authors are 100% consistent in how they use terms, so seeing how it's used in this specific context can help you get more accurate answers.

A Goal Based Agent Behavior, is the Behavior of a Goal Based Agent.
A Goal Based Agent is an Agent that is designed to reach a Goal state. That is in constrast with being an Utility Based Agent, which is an Agent that is designed to maximize some variable or Utility function.
By "Behavior" we mean a mapping (or function, or algorithm) that takes the perception of the agent and yields the action the agent takes.
And yes, we can use Goal Oriented Action Planning (GOAP) to implement the Goal Based Agent Behavior. In particular the current state for GOAP would be the perception of the agent, and GOAP would give us what action the agent will take.

So tl;dr: Goal-based action planning is a way to achieve goal-based agent behavior?
